# Tensorflow Serving: Expects arg[0] to be float but string is provided

Tags: json, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Tensorflow Serving returns the error message in the title and I don't understand why. I call it via the regress API as it is shown in the below snippet:

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var client_myclient = new RestClient("http://192.168.100.1:8501/v1/models/mymodel:regress");
// request preparation
json_prep.examples.Add( blah blah blah);
string json_prep_converted = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json_prep, Formatting.Indented);
var req_ = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
req_.AddJsonBody(json_prep_converted);
// response
var res_mymodel = client_myclient.Execute(req_candle);
```

My error message contains the following request confirming what I sent; it is only a single example exactly as shown below except that the ... omits several entries:

```
{
  "examples": [
    {
      "a": [
        1.937336,
        ...
        -5.107522
      ],
      "b": [
        -0.704486,
        ...
        -6.868737
      ],
      "c": [
        2.817943,
        ...
        -4.226915
      ],
      "d": [
        -3.346308,
        -...
        -7.749344
      ],
      "e": [
        1.0625,
        -0.1875,
        ...
        -0.8125
      ],
      "f": [
        0.943968,
        -1.17052,
        ...
        0.641898
      ],
      "g": [
        0.22639801,
        ...
        0.19194462
      ],
      "h": [
        -1.449828,
        ...
        0.34936
      ],
      "i": [
        -50.61624,
        ...
        -17.362056
      ],
      "j": [
        0.148651,
        ...
        -0.228189
      ],
      "k": [
        0.16410813748132047,
        ...
        0.39454449551653981
      ],
      "l": [
        0.704047,
        ...
        -1.462873
      ],
      "m": [
        4.55,
        ...
        2.54
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON message was double checked and it doesn't contain strings where I replaced the list body with ... (And it must not by definition)
I trying to follow the [official manual on this](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/api_rest#request_format).

For more details, the error in raw format is:

```
"{ \"error\": \"Expects arg[0] to be float but string is provided\" }"
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the SignatureDefs of that model using the command,

```
saved_model_cli show --dir /usr/local/google/home/abc/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu/00000123 --all
```

As you said you are performing Inference for Regress Signature, the Signature Definition for your Model should be :

```
signature_def['regress_x_to_y']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: tf_example:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['outputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: y:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/regress
```

I got the similar error as yours when my Input Data Type was `DT_FLOAT` instead of `DT_STRING`.

Regress and Classify Signatures expect Input Data Type to be `DT_STRING` (tf.examples). So, changing it accordingly should resolve your issue.